# Installing JOGL

Tags: java, jogl

Well, consider me an absolute derp, but I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to get the JOGL libraries.  I can't find them anywhere.  Most sites seem to link to https://jogl.dev.java.net/ which 404's, or to http://jogamp.org/ which doesn't seem to host the .jar files.  Do I have to build from source?

Comment: Was in the same boat - there's some resource links on here, together with a useful beginners guide to deciphering which jars are actually needed. http://schabby.de/jogl-example-hello-world

Comment: Schabby's guide is overcomplicated and contains some errors that he refused to fix especially in his videos. Please rather use our official instructions on jogamp.org in the wiki.

Comment: The instructions to download and install JOGL are in our wiki: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_JOGL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some googling, I've found this page:

- [jogamp-current](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/)
- [jogl latest version/archive](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/) (contains the latest version and jars in 7z format)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I swear I looked bloody everywhere for that damn thing.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens sometimes to everyone, maybe get some fresh air and relax a min or two, then back to the work :).